# Error "Cannot open database requested by the login. Login failed" while running Invoke-sqlcmd

Tags: powershell, invoke-sqlcmd

I am not able to figure out why `invoke-sqlcmd` is not working. It's giving login failed error. This user has sysadmin permissions.

When the azure release pipeline runs, if the database does not exist then it restores the new database from the `.bak` file, and I am using `invoke-sqlcmd` command for that. When I try to run the `select` statement using `invoke-sqlcmd` it works fine but while doing the DB restore it does not seem to work and I cannot figure out why.

The error is below:

> Invoke-sqlcmd - cannot open database requested by login. The login failed

Comment: I was able to resolve this issue. I was calling the database name in the invoke-sqlcmd which it did not like. Somebody replied in another forum and it resolved my issue. below command solved my problem 
invoke-sqlcmd -ServerInstance $server -Database master -Username $sqlusername -Password $sqlpassword -Query $sql
Earlier i was using $dbname instead of master

Comment: Please post this as an answer to your question and mark it as Accepted, so that it helps other people too! Not everyone might go through the comments on the question.